# Unable to update managed package

Tags: managed-package, package-install

We are having issues with updating a managed package after releasing a new version.

I logged a case with SF, long story short is they suggest we are best off just creating a new package.

The error code is: myRule_13015i000001NBegAAG: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 154417921-245834 (-509259376)

Which is 'Process Flow Migration' which must have been created when we migrated a PB to a flow.

It's just strange as we haven't touched the flow for several versions and it's been fine, updated fine and worked fine.

But suddenly something is wrong.

Any help or ideas on this would be great.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. However, I wanted to say that if support really said "just create a new package" they are losing the plot. That's not an acceptable answer. You should escalate if you can.

Comment: Mate I was literally blown away, I was on a call with them, and I said what about all our subscriber orgs they can no longer get upgrades?? and he said 'Seems like a pretty big problem' I'm sure I can get it sorted but sort of left me feeling alone in the dark.

Comment: Have you posted in the Partner Community? You might be able to get more visibility and traction from non-Support stakeholders there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar scenario a while back. I had a field which had a lot of dependencies in flow and it wasn't allowing to upgrade. It was deleted by one of my team member. Try asking SF to Enable manage package component deletion and delete this component from the package. (Make sure it has no dependencies)

P.S. Try getting their premier plan. They don't really have lot of options available for their standard plan.